# Angular 6 - Getting string with @Input operator. Value not known

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have 2 components: Parent and Child.

I the child component I have an @Input operator:

**child.component.ts:**

```
@Input() position: string;
```

**child.comppnent.html**

```
<div>{{position}}</div>
```

Then on my parent.component.html I have:

```
<app-child [position]="top-left"></app-child>
```

The problem is that it's giving me and error saying it doesn't know "top-left" so it's asking me to add the value of top-left to the parent.component.html.

**My question is:**

Is there a way for it to accept the value added on [position]="" without having to add any code to the parent.component.ts ?

Comment: if you use "top-left" as string do `<app-child position="top-left"></app-child>` without the `[]` brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the value of your parents attribute `position` wrapped in single quotes.

```
<app-child [position]="'top-left'"></app-child>
```

The first Double quote is for angular the second indicate string so angular wioll pass your top-left as a string variable.So basically what you need is

`top-left` i.e `[position]=" 'top-left' "`

Answer (score 0):

Put the value of your parents attribute `position` wrapped in single quotes.

```
<app-child [position]="'top-left'"></app-child>
```

This was will treat the value as a value instead of a reference to a variable.

Comment: sorry i unknowingly edited your answer, please reject my edit if you don't need it. :)

Comment: I accepted it, it was clearer than what I put originally!

Comment: Although we have duplicated answers :D

Comment: Why are both answer text the same ?

Comment: @Craig2018, Nuru Salihu accidentally edited my answer and I accepted. I rolled back to not confuse anyone.